# js masonry stuck in one column with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

Masonry all of a sudden is just showing me 1 column

Been messing with this one for a while, what can it be? float: left on the item doesn't fix the problem, leaves gaps obviously.

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#containermason');

  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.item',
      columnWidth: '260px'
    });
  });

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '.pagination',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '.pagination a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
      finishedMsg: '<p style="background: #82d63e; margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 10px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;">that\'s all the content</p>',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/C1U8WRZ.gif'
      }
    },
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      // hide new items while they are loading
      var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
      // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
      $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        // show elems now they're ready
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 

      });
 $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    });

});
```

the container is not positioned to absolute or anything, I can't understand why.I've been frustrated all night about this.

the boxes are in the partial:

```
<div class="column-center"  id="main" >
    <div id="containermason" class="js-masonry">

     <%= render :partial => "mypost", :locals => {mypost: mypost}, :collection => mypost %>

    </div>
  </div>
```

and in the partial i have item:

```
 <div id="streamline"  class="item">

        ...code....

</div>
```

and css for items:

```
.item {
       background: #fff; 
       margin: 10px;  
       width: 241px; 
       padding: 2px;  
       border-radius: 10px;

      }
```

Comment: can you post the HTML/CSS as well?

Comment: I see people adding `float: left;` to the css, but is that even part of the setup? When I do that it leaves gaps

Comment: just asking: is `#containermason` maybe cutted of when defining `$container`? Then it would be just a typo ...

Comment: cut off? Not sure what you mean

Comment: in your code it says: `var $container = $('#containermason');` and maybe you have `#containermasonry` in your HTML.  Just guessing... And the `float: left` was needed in older version, when i remember correctly, but can now be omitted.

Comment: oh no, it's `#containermason`

Comment: can you set `columnWidth` to `265px` (margin + padding + width + padding + margin) - the rest looks fine

Comment: I just noticed that you are initializing masonry twice. via HTML (`.js-masonry`) and via JS. Maybe that is the problem. The HTML version doesn't get any options and no columnWidth. So maybe removing that `class="js-masonry"` will fix it

Comment: nothing, unfortunately

Comment: sorry man, looks all fine to me. When you say "all of the sudden" - what did you change? did it work before?

Comment: the javascript, I messed with it to get the infinitescroll

Comment: maybe the JS breaks somewhere due to infiniteScroll and masonry doesn't even get initialized. Can you see any DOM modifications done by masonry when inspecting the items?

Comment: yeah, something with initialization

Comment: what does your console say?

Comment: masonry('appended', elem) only takes two parameters - you have three - maybe that caused problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but after the line:

```
 $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
```

try adding a call to 'layout' wrapped in a timeout:

```
 $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
 window.setTimeout(function() {
      $container.masonry('layout');
 }, 1000);
```

You can adjust the value of 1000. Try making it bigger (2000, then 3000...) if it doesn't work; or if it does work, try making it smaller until it breaks again.

If this hack does fix your problem then it suggests there is an issue with things loading in the page. Masonry seems very sensitive to everything being loaded and laid-out before it can correctly do its own layout. So this hack helps you diagnose the problem and provides a workaround, but isn't the ideal solution.

Are you working on a tumblr template? (Some of the code looks like Tumblr). If so you might find this question useful. Or if not, this Q relates to a Tumblr template that was using infiniteScroll and Masonry, so it may help anyway!

[Images loaded JavaScript - Using jQuery Masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149318/images-loaded-javascript-using-jquery-masonry/25149913#25149913)

There's a few ideas in that relating to Masonry layouts and Tumblr and in the end the accepted answer was the timeout I suggested!